# Invalid moz:firefoxOptions field unexpectedAlertBehaviour

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to upgrade from selenium 2.53 to 3.5.2 (c#, Selenium webdriver)
Upgraded the packeges through Nuget package Manager. 
FF verion 52.0

Im trying to Instantiate firefox

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior, "ignore");
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Exception is

> Result Message:   System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid
>   moz:firefoxOptions field unexpectedAlertBehaviour

Comment: Can you try with- `options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior, "accept");` ?

Comment: I believe this is no longer supported. See this for available options https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I am using for firefox. I did not see your path to geckodriver so I am adding in full code. I had the same error but I am thinking this is a bug. My guess is they have not introduced this yet with gecko.

```
var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path to GeckoDriver"));
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
 options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
// options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior, "accept");
your_Driver= new FirefoxDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
your_Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
_wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```